# $.post to send something to database on click with ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I have a 5 star rating jQuery widget on my page (that i created). It takes a function to handle its on click value. Previously this is what i had it do:

```
$('.fivestar').each(function() {
    $(this).ratings(5, $js_tile_data[$posValue][6]).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {
        $.post('jRating/send_rating.php?whichpage='+$page+'&id='+$js_tile_data[$posValue][0]+'&rating='+data.rating);
        $(this).clickable(false);
    });
});
```

Now i am using ruby on rails and want to achieve the same effect, storing the rating value to my database without loading a new page or anything. Also, if possible, i don't want to have to click a button or link or anything like that. Everything i have found trying to figure out how to do this requires a link or form or button.

Any help or direction to where to look would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Alright this is what i have in my function call:

```
$.post('/send_rating?whichpage=eat&id='+$js_tile["id"]+'&rating='+data.rating);
```

And then send_raing_controller.rb:

```
class SendRatingController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @page = params[:whichPage]
    @id = params[:id]
    @rating = params[:rating]

    if (@page = "eat")
      @tile = EatTile.find(@id)
      @newVotes = @tile.num_votes + 1
      @newRating = (($tile.rating *@tile.num_votes) + @rating) / @newVotes
      @tile.num_votes = @newVotes
      @tile.rating = @newRating
    end
  end
end
```

i used create because when i rake routes the post function goes to create. It isn't working properly, would it be because of the way i find the EatPage? Or is it not getting called correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify how you would set the rating without clicking on something?  Are you trying to do more than port the PHP code to RoR?

Comment: no nothing more than that, and i only want to have to click the div that the rating widget is in, not a link or button

Comment: okay, so this is strictly a question asking how to write a rating change to a database in Ruby?  Cause assuming you have that part, the only change in your javascript is the URL.

Comment: yeah i suppose so, and how to fit it into the rails framework properly

Comment: I'd drop the javascript tag, and provide the PHP code you want to port - the progress you've made so far in Ruby, and see if someone can provide a bit of help there.

Comment: @FilmJ alright i updated it if you wouldn't mind taking a look. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't worked with rails in awhile, but this seems like a typo:   `if (@page = "eat")`.  Did you mean `if (@page == "eat")`

Answer (score 1):

You may already have the following, but I just re-cap what you need

I assume you already know how rails work with controller, model, view (MVC)

First, you will need a controller to handle the request (No matter post or get or put or else)

Second, in your controller, you can get what you pass in the url by params[:xxx]

In your case, params[:whichpage], params[:id] ...

After that, response with text or javascript or what ever you want
I usually use a js.erb to response with javascript for update the view or just alert a message

Or even just call a predefine javascript callback

Comment: i updated with what i have tried, if you could take a luck i would appreciate it!

Comment: 1, if you don't need the variable available in view, no need to add a "@". 2, `@page == "eat"` not "=". 3, `@tile.save` to write that to db

Comment: right, also i need to add respond to format.js right? (at work right now can't try it)

Comment: well, rails automatically handle that, you just need to create a create.js.erb in views/send_rating/ and add any javascript you want and you are good to go